# Merge and QuickSort - stack overloaded

Tags: c++, sorting, stack, quicksort, mergesort

Helo everyone. :)
I have to write a program where I have 4 types of sorting: bubble-, insertion-, merge- i quick-sort.
Program has to sort points x,y in array of structures (random) by amount of total of their coordinates //e.g.: (1,3) is less than (0,6) because 1+3<0+6//. It saves sorted ones in this same array and also in txt file with time of sorting by each B,I,M,Q-sort.

Code from Merge and MergeSort:

```
void Merge(Structure *tab, int A, int sr, int Z)
{   
    Structure *tmp = new Structure[Z];
    int i;
    for (i = A; i <= Z; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i] = tab[i];
    }
    i = A;
    int j = sr + 1;
    int q = A;
    while (i <= sr && j <= Z)
    {
        if (Compare(tab, i, j)) //'Compare' tells if total of coordinates from tab[i] is bigger than total from tab[j]
        {
            tab[q] = tmp[i];
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            tab[q] = tmp[j];
            ++i;
        }
        ++q;
    }
    if(i <= sr)
    {
        while (i <= sr)
        {
            tab[q] = tmp[i];
            ++i;
            ++q;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(j <= Z)
        {
            tab[q] = tmp[j];
            ++j;
            ++q;
        }
    }

    delete[] tmp; 
}

void MergeSort(Structure *tab, int A, int Z)
{
    int sr = (A + Z)/2;
    if(A < Z)
    {
        MergeSort(tab, A, sr);
        MergeSort(tab, sr + 1, Z);
        Merge(tab, A, sr, Z);
    }
}
```

And to QuickSort:

```
int DivideQS(Structure *tab, int A, int Z)
{
    Structure tmp;
    Structure pivot = tab[A]; // first el. for pivot (A=0)
    int i = A, j = Z; //indexes in array
    while (true)
    {
        while (Compare(tab, j, A))
        j--;
        while (!Compare(tab, i, A)) // until elements are lower than pivot,       that's this '!' for
        i++;
        if (i < j) // swap when i < j
        {
            tmp = tab[i];
            tab[i] = tab[j];
            tab[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        return j;
    }
}
void QuickSort(Structure *tab, int A, int Z)
{
    int dziel;
    if (A < Z)
    {  
        dziel = DivideQS(tab, A, Z);
        QuickSort(tab, A, dziel);
        QuickSort(tab, dziel+1, Z);
    }
}
```

My problem is a stack. No matter how big I make this, it still goes overloaded. I can't manage this problem. I don't know if that's because of mistake in code or it's somewhere else. Bubble and Insertion work impeccable.
I was looking for solving on many sites, in my language and foreign ones (I'm Pole), and modificating code in so many ways but still have no clue what to do.
Help me, please.

===================================

How could I be so blind! Thank you @user3187084. :D
But I think I went from bad to worse. Now I've received new error message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Projekt_AiSD.exe.
>   This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Projekt_AiSD.exe or any >of the DLLs it has loaded.
>   This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Projekt_AiSD.exe has focus.
>   The output window may have more diagnostic information.

And after that this showed to me: http://i40.tinypic.com/314qyl5.png

And this is code for checking:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Structure
{
int x;
int y;
};
bool Compare(Structure *tab, int i, int j)
{
    if ( (tab[i].x + tab[i].y) > (tab[j].x + tab[j].y))
        return true;
    return false;
}
void LosujWspolrzedne(Structure* tab, int K)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) 
    {
        tab[i].x = rand()%21;
        tab[i].y = rand()%21;
    }
    //return;
}
void Save (Structure *tab, int K, string NazwaPliku)
{
    ofstream zap(NazwaPliku); 
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        zap << tab[i].x << ' ' << tab[i].y << endl;

    }
    zap.close();
}
void Load (Structure *tab, int K, string NazwaPliku)
{
    ifstream wcz(NazwaPliku);
    if (!wcz)
    {
        cout << "Can't open the file!!!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i)
    {
        wcz >> tab[i].x >> tab[i].y;
    }
    wcz.close();
}
void Time(long long a, long long b, string NazwaPliku)
{
    ofstream czas(NazwaPliku);
    if (!czas)
    {
        cout << "Can't open the file!!!" << endl;
    }
    czas << (b - a) << " ms" << endl;
    czas.close();
}
void CopyArray(Structure *tab, Structure *tab1, int K)  
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < K ; i++) 
    {
        tab1[i].x = tab[i].x;
        tab1[i].y = tab[i].y;
    }
}
void Call_MS(Structure *tab, int A, int K)
{
    Load(tab, K, "1k.txt");
    long long startTime = GetTickCount64();
    MergeSort(tab, A, K-1);
    long long endTime = GetTickCount64();
    cout << (endTime - startTime) << "ms dla MergeSort" << endl;
    Save(tab, K, "WartLos_MS_1k.txt");
    Time(startTime, endTime, "WartLos_MS_1k_czas.txt");
}
void Call_QS(Structure *tab, int A, int K)
{
    Load(tab, K, "1k.txt");
    long long startTime = GetTickCount64();
    QuickSort(tab, A, K-1);
    long long endTime = GetTickCount64();
    cout << (endTime - startTime) << "ms dla QuickSort" << endl;
    Save(tab, K, "WartLos_QS_1k.txt");
    Time(startTime, endTime, "WartLos_QS_1k_czas.txt");
}

const int MAX_EL = 30;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Structure *punkt = new Structure[MAX_EL];

    void LosujWspolrzedne(Structure *punkt, int MAX_EL);

Structure *punkt1= new Structure[MAX_EL];
void CopyArray(Structure *punkt, Structure *punkt1, int MAX_EL);                      
delete[] punkt;

Save(punkt1, MAX_EL, "1k.txt");

cout<<"Start:"<<endl;

Call_MS(punkt1, 0, MAX_EL);
Call_QS(punkt1, 0, MAX_EL);

delete[] punkt1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi - it would help if you present the minimum code which has the problem. Also when you say 'my problem is a stack' can you give more details?

Comment: If neither merge-sort nor quick-sort are working, these are two separate questions, and should be separated into two separate [so] questions (and you should post [a short, runnable program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can see the results for ourselves, not just the applicable functions). But you really should debug the code and check that it's doing what you expect (if you're unsure what it should be doing, you should work through an example by hand so you know what each value should be at each step).

Comment: Sorry, but I thought it'll be faster, copy both problems to one post. I hope so it doesn't bother too much to create new topic. If it is, I'll do it. I debugged program which I just dropped, previous too. It stops at "delete[] tmp;", last line in Merge.

Comment: I put code to new project and instead good news I received new-but-not-good ones. Besides error: "Windows has triggered a breakpoint..." there came mlock.c with: http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ae5rvn&s=5#.UtK4s9LuJpA . I really don't know what more can I do. Any ideas/hints, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have MergeSort(tab, A, Z) inside MergeSort, so you always call itself with exact arguments

It should be MergeSort(tab, A, st)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `MergeSort(tab,A,Z)` which call the same function again with same arguments which is will go one for infinite recursion hence error. You should only pass `MergeSort(tab,A,sr)` which will reduce your problem to half size.